# Instance variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Ruby 1.9

I suddenly realize I don't understand how to define and initialize an instance variable in Ruby. It must be used **only within** a certain `class` and not accessible out of a class at all, so `attr_accessor` or `attr_reader` is not what I need.

```
class MyClass

  #how do I initialize it?
  @my_var = 'some value'

  def method1
    #I need to do something with @my_var
    puts @my_var
  end
  def method2
    #I need to do something with @my_var
    puts @my_var
  end
end

a = MyClass.new
a.method1 #empty 
a.method2 #empty
```

So I found that there is another way to do it

```
class MyClass

  #is this the only way to do it?
  def initialize
    @my_var = 555
  end

  def method1
    #I need to do something with @my_var
    puts @my_var
  end

  def method2
    #I need to do something with @my_var
    puts @my_var
  end
end

a = MyClass.new
a.method1 #555; it's ok
a.method2 #555; it's ok
```

Well, is second approach the right one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

each class has an `initialize()` method that acts similar to a constructor in other languages, instance variables should be initialized there:

```
class MyClass

  def initialize
     @my_var = 'some value'
  end

  # etc...
end
```

Comment: They can be initialized only in the method (contructor) `initialize()`? It's my question.

Comment: They can be initialized in any instance method but `initialize` is the first method called for any given instance so it's the best place to do it.

Comment: Why can't it be initialized out of any method? `class MyClass @my_var = 'some value' ;end` ?

Comment: Whenever you create an instance variable it gets associated with whatever the current value of `self` is, outside of any method if would get associated with the `MyClass` class object, inside of a method `self` refers to the current instance of `MyClass`. So if you initialized outside of the method it would be associated with  the class itself rather than a specific instance of that class.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `initialize` is the right way.

But you may also make:

```
class MyClass

  def method1
    #I need to do something with @my_var
    puts @my_var ||= 555
  end

  def method2=(x)
    #I need to do something with @my_var
    puts @my_var = x
  end
end

#Test:
x = MyClass.new
x.method1      #555
x.method2= 44  #44
x.method1      #44
```

When `method1`is called the first time, it initialize the variable.

**Edit:** 
It does not work as expected, when you assign `nil`

```
x = MyClass.new
x.method1         #555
x.method2= nil   #nil
x.method1          #again 555
```

This version works better:

```
class MyClass

  def method1
    @my_var = 555 unless defined? @my_var
    puts @my_var 
  end

  def method2=(x)
    puts @my_var = x
  end
end

x = MyClass.new
x.method1         #555
x.method2= nil   #nil
x.method1          #keeps nil
```

Comment: This is the lazy definition pattern.